# grep: Find all files containing the word `star`, but not the word `start`

Tags: grep

I have a bunch of files: some contain the word `star`, some contain the word `start`, some contain both.

I'd like to grep for files that contain the word `star`, but not the word `start`.

How can this be accomplished using only grep?

Comment: Inverse match on start

Comment: Is piping two greps together cheating?

Comment: Please provide concise, testable sample input and expected output as different people are interpreting your text in different ways. Include a file that only contains `star`, a file that only contains `start`, and a file that contains both. Right now we don't know what you're searching for in the files or what the output should be (the file name, the matching line, both, or something else?) and that missing [mcve] would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` has some options for inverting the matches at the line or file level. You want the latter option, with the `-L` switch. The following will print the names of all the files in a folder that *don't* contain the text `start`:

```
grep -LF start *
```

`-F` tells grep that `start` is a literal string and not a regex. It's optional here, but might speed things up a tiny bit.

You can use the resulting list to search for files that contain `star`:

```
grep -lF star $(grep -LF start *)
```

`-l` prints only the names of files containing a match, not any line-by-line or match-by-match details. If this is not exactly what you want, `man grep` is your friend.

This uses an additional shell construct to run the inverted match, but it technically doesn't call any additional programs that aren't `grep`.

**Update**

Since you mention wanting to look through all the files starting with a given root folder, change `-LF` to `-LFr`. Replace `*` with your root folder if you don't want to change working directories.

`-r` tells `grep` to recurse into directories, and search every file it finds along the way.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! So close! `grep -LF start *` throws a lot of errors (vis. `grep: foo: Is a directory`). Any way to get rid of those?

Comment: @StudentsTea Do you want to look at files in `foo/`, or do you only want the files directly in the current directory?

Comment: @StudentsTea. Couple of ways. Best is just pass in the actual list of files you are interested in. You can still use wildcards: something like `*.txt` for example. You can suppress the errors with `2> /dev/null` or so. If you actually want to look into those folders instead, add `-r` to your flags.

Comment: @DanielH I want to look in every file in the subtree starting from the directory where grep is run.

Comment: Then add a `-r` option to the inner `grep`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist to suppress errors, use the `-s` option... and I would suggest to use `grep -rLZ 'start' | xargs -0 grep -l 'star'` to avoid issues due to filenames containing space, newlines, etc... also, worth mentioning that `grep -rwl 'star'` will match whole word star but not words like start, starry, mustard, etc..

Comment: @Sundeep. Excellent points all. I stayed away from find and xargs because the question asked for grep only.

Comment: @Sundeep. Also keep in mind that while `-rwl star` may be useful in the outer grep, it won't help with the initial filtering step, unless of course words like `startled` are in fact ok.

Comment: yeah, OP specifically mentioned using grep alone.. but I'd argue that both `xargs` and `$()` are playing the same role here.. may be just point out potential file name issues as a note... and I was aiming for `-rwl` as a single grep solution, mentioning the behavior of word boundaries.. let OP decide if that solves or 2 greps are indeed needed

Comment: I completely agree that `xargs` or `find` would be better here. But `-rwl` would not help you to a one step solution because you'd still be left with the problem of discarding files containing both words.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep for `-w`:

```
$ cat file
foo star bar
oof start rab

$ grep -w star *
foo star bar
```

or if you just want the names of the files containing `star`:

```
$ grep -lw star *
file
```

and to just find files to look in:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -w 'star' {} \;
foo star bar
```

Comment: But what about discarding that same file from the list when it also contains `start`?

Comment: Specifically, OP's stated requirement is "grep for files that contain the word star, but not the word start."

Comment: Apparently we are interpreting the requirements differently. I don't think the OP wants to exclude files that contain the word `start`, I think she's simply saying that she wants to find the word `star` but not when it's part of another word like `start`. I'll ask for some sample input/output (which we should have done in the first place before posting answers :-( ).

Comment: When you put it that way, it makes sense.